# python connect to microsoft sql server db

Tags: python, sql-server, database

I am trying to access a microsoft sql server DB trough python but I am receiving `Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified')`

The only info that I have is the db ip, user, password and db name. I used dbevear to set the connection and it's ok but I need to get data with python.
I tried the following:

```
import pypyodbc 
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(
                        "Server=171.11.111.11;"
                        "Database=database_name;"
                        "uid=my_username;pwd=secret")
df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from db.dtable', cnxn)
```

I am quite new to python and I don't exactly how to connect to the db. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you want to fill pandas arrays fast you may also want to check out: <https://github.com/pacman82/arrow-odbc-py>. Full disclosure: I am the author.

Answer (score 1):

This

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'

means you failed to specify which ODBC driver you want to use.  See eg

```
import pyodbc 
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = 'tcp:myserver.database.windows.net' 
database = 'mydb' 
username = 'myusername' 
password = 'mypassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

[Connecting to SQL Server using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Seems you answered the quesition 20s before I did. How do I remove my answer?

Comment: upss, found it.